# Adding a sequence group number based on the column value

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I have a panel data that looks like this:

```
ID TFvalue Date        
1    0     2021-01-01     
1    0     2021-02-01     
1    1     2021-03-01     
1    1     2021-04-01     
2    0     2021-01-10     
2    1     2021-02-10    
2    0     2021-03-10    
2    0     2021-04-10     
3    1     2021-01-05     
3    1     2021-02-05     
3    0     2021-03-05    
3    1     2021-04-05
```

I need to group rows for each id until 1 from `TFvalue` comes up. Every time 1 from `TFvalue` shows up, a new group, sequence number needs to be given afterwards. For example, what I need is ...

```
ID TFvalue Date         GroupNum
1    0     2021-01-01     1
1    0     2021-02-01     1
1    1     2021-03-01     1
1    1     2021-04-01     2
2    0     2021-01-10     1
2    1     2021-02-10     1
2    0     2021-03-10     2
2    0     2021-04-10     2
3    1     2021-01-05     1
3    1     2021-02-05     2
3    0     2021-03-05     3
3    1     2021-04-05     3
```

I tried `Dense_Rank()` but I failed to get what I want. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the previous value of `TFvalue` to get a `flag` column which will be `1` if that previous value is `1` or `null`, or `0` if the previous value is `0`.
Then with `SUM()` window function you get the column `GroupNum`:

```
SELECT ID, TFvalue, Date, 
       SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) GroupNum
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(TFvalue, 1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) flag
  FROM tablename
) t;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f63349d87463b706a99184c664c507cc).